# How can I set height:100% on child of flex item that has flex-grow:1?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Why does setting `height:100%` to the child of a flex item (that is also a flex container) that has `flex-grow:1` isn't working as expected?

Setting `height: 100%` to this child element should make it take the height of it's parent (the `flex-grow:1` parent) but it doesn't so I'm clearly wrong.
I want to know what `height:100%` means in this context. Why doesn't the item take the full height of it's parent with this setting.

This is the HTML (Bootstrap needed)

```css
.theHeader {
    background-color: #336B87;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.project-manager {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.flex-grow-this {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid flex-content">
    <header class="container-fluid theHeader">
        <h1 class="logo">ToDo Manager</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid row flex-grow-this">
        <aside class="col-2 project-manager">
            sek
        </aside>
        <section class="col-10 to-do-list">

        </section>
    </div>
</div><!--end of main div-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues that are resolved by cleaning up the code, and [correctly using the Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/). 
The layout should simply be `container-fluid` > `row` > `columns`. Don't use nested containers. You don't need the extra CSS for flexbox and height. Bootstrap 4 includes [Utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/) for this:

- flex-grow-1
- d-flex flex-column
- vh-100

Just add CSS for the colors/borders/padding...

```
.theHeader {
    background-color: #336B87;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.project-manager {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Then the HTML is simply...

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
    <header class="theHeader">
        <h1 class="logo">ToDo Manager</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1">
        <div class="row flex-grow-1">
            <aside class="col-2 project-manager">
                aside
            </aside>
            <section class="col-10 to-do-list">

            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: adding `height:100%` to the child `col-2` will actually prevent it from filling the height of the parent. Just make sure the parent `row` is `flex-grow-1`

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/IHAHhF8qEa

Comment: Thanks. Just one question. Why does "adding height:100% to the child col-2 will actually prevent it from filling the height of the parent". How does that work?

Comment: Because `height:100%` makes it fill the height of the parent row. Since the parent row doesn't have a defined height, it's just filling the natural height of the row which is set by the height of its content.

Comment: So the child element doesn't recognize the parent's element "flex-grow: 1;" as a reference height, since it isn't a "defined height" or "explicit height". Is this statement accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding h-100 class to the parent div

```html
<div class="container-fluid flex-content">
      <header class="container-fluid theHeader">
        <h1 class="logo">ToDo Manager</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="container-fluid row flex-grow-this h-100" >
        <aside class="col-2 project-manager">
                    sek
                </aside>
        <section class="col-10 to-do-list">
asd
                </section>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You have not set margin and padding of body to zero, that's why it is leaving space from top. See the snippet.

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.theHeader {
    background-color: #336B87;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.project-manager {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.flex-grow-this {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid flex-content">
    <header class="container-fluid theHeader">
        <h1 class="logo">ToDo Manager</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid row flex-grow-this">
        <aside class="col-2 project-manager">
            sek
        </aside>
        <section class="col-10 to-do-list">

        </section>
    </div>
</div><!--end of main div-->
```